# Update collection with data from Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have method that returns Dictionary with value `true/false`

Here is this method

```
public Dictionary<IItemWithRules, bool> CheckAvailability(List<IItemWithRules> tiles)
{
     //...
}
```

I want to update one value in collection with this method

Here is code where I want to use it

```
public List<ActionMenuItemModel> GetAvailableMenuActions()
{
    var actions = this.actionMenuItemBllFactory.Create()
                      .GetListBy(
                          a => a.Active,
                          z => z.SelectNested(a => a.AvailabilityRules));

     var filteredItems = this.rulesService.FilterItemsWithRules(actions)
                             .OrderBy(a => a.Order)
                            
                             .ToList();


    return this.networkAvailabilityService.CheckAvailability(new List<IItemWithRules>(filteredItems))
                   .Keys.Select(x => new ActionMenuItemModel((ActionMenuItem)x))
                   .ToList();
}
```

Here is `ActionMenuItemModel`

```
public class ActionMenuItemModel
{
    public ActionMenuItemModel()
    {
    }

    public ActionMenuItemModel(ActionMenuItem domainModel)
    {
        this.Id = domainModel.Id;
        this.Label = domainModel.Label;
        this.Href = domainModel.Href;
        this.Target = domainModel.Target;
        this.Icon = domainModel.Icon?.Content;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; init; }

    public string Label { get; init; }

    public string Href { get; init; }

    public string Target { get; init; }

    public string Icon { get; init; }

    public bool IsAvailable { get; init; }
}
```

I need to update `IsAvailable` fields in this row

```
return this.networkAvailabilityService.CheckAvailability(new List<IItemWithRules>(filteredItems))
                   .Keys.Select(x => new ActionMenuItemModel((ActionMenuItem)x))
                   .ToList();
```

with value from dictionary

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
.Keys.Select(x => new ActionMenuItemModel((ActionMenuItem)x))
```

to this

```
.Select(x => new ActionMenuItemModel((ActionMenuItem)x.Key) { IsAvailable = x.Value })
```

---

So, rather than iterating through the `Keys` collection, you should iterate through the dictionary where each element (`x`) is a `KeyValuePair<IItemWithRules, bool>`